# Propper Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to check the incoming string and leave only characters, matching:

- small case a-z letters
- _ character
- any numbers
- only one dot (first one)

  ```
  $string = 'contDADdas7.6.asdASDj_@@e1!Ddd__aa#S.txt';
  $pattern = "/[a-z_0-9]+/";
  preg_match_all("/[a-z_0-9]+/", $name, $result);
  echo implode('', $result[0]);
  ```

has to be

```
contdas7.6asdj_e1dd__aatxt
```

It matches first three points, how can I take only one first dot ?

Comment: You want to replace no desired chars? is that right?

Comment: Yes, only first dot in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$string = strrev($string);
$string = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9_.]++|\.(?![^.]*$)~', '', $string);
$string = strrev($string);
```

An other way:

```
$strs = explode('.', $string);
if (count($strs)>1) {
    $strs[0] .= '.' . $strs[1];
    unset($strs[1]);
}
$string = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9_.]++~', '', implode('', $strs));
```

Comment: Won't this output `contdas76asdj_e1dd__aa.txt` instead of `contdas7.6asdj_e1dd__aatxt`?

Comment: @anubhava: No because the string has been reversed before.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = "contDADdas7.6.asdASDj_@@e1!Ddd__aa#S.txt";
    preg_match_all("/[a-z_0-9\.]+/", $str, $match);
    $newstr = implode("", $match[0]);
    echo substr_replace(str_replace(".", "", $newstr), ".", strpos($newstr, "."), 0);
```

**Output**:

```
contdas7.6asdj_e1dd__aatxt
```